# How to setup a generic interface for the state when using React useReducer with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, use-reducer

I face this problem when I try to setup an interface to the state when trying to use useReducer.I use it in a custom hook for fetching data from the server. The data object in response from the server may contain different properties.
the useFetcher.ts

```
const initialState = {
  data: null,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};
type LIST_RESPONSE = {
  page: number;
  totalRows: number;
  pageSize: number;
  totalPages: number;
  list: [];
};
interface State {
  data: LIST_RESPONSE| null;
  loading: boolean;
  error: string | null;
}
const reducer = (state: State, action: ACTIONTYPES) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.FETCHING: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    }
    case ACTIONS.FETCH_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: action.data,
      };
    }
    case ACTIONS.ERROR: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.error,
      };
    }
  }
};

const useFetcher = (url: string): State => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const { data, loading, error } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.FETCHING });
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await httpService.get(url);
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.FETCH_SUCCESS, data: response.data });
        return;
      } catch (error: unknown) {
        const { message } = error as Error;
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.ERROR, error: message });
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);
  return { data, loading, error };
};

export default useFetcher;
```

Component A call useFetcher:

```
 const { data, loading, error } = useFetcher('productList');
```

this works fine, it returns the data object that fits the LIST_RESPONSE type. but if I want want to use the useFetcher function in Component B, it is expected to return another data type, let's say like this:

```
type CATEGORTY_RESPONSE= {
  categories: [];
};
```

How can I make the data type in the interface State generic? for example, I can define the data type in the State interface when I am calling the useFecher hook like this:
component A:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useFetcher<LIST_RESPONSE>('productList');
```

component B:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useFetcher<CATEGORTY_RESPONSE>('categories');
```

I tried

```
interface State {
  data: LIST_RESPONSE|CATEGORTY_RESPONSE| null;
  loading: boolean;
  error: string | null;
}
```

or

```
const useFetcher = <Type extends State>(url: string): Type =>{...}
```

none of them works.
Any help?thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Creating a Generic Hook

In order to use a generic, you will need to apply that generic at multiple points in the chain:

- The `useFetcher` hook needs to know what state type it returns.
- The `useReducer` hook needs to know the type of the reducer.
- The `reducer` needs to know the type of its state and actions.
- The `State` needs to know the type for its `data` property.
- The success action needs to know the type for its `data` property.

Here's what that looks like:

```
import {useEffect, useReducer, Reducer} from "react";

enum ACTIONS {
    FETCHING = 'FETCHING',
    FETCH_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_SUCCESS',
    ERROR = 'ERROR'
}

type ACTIONTYPES<DataType> = {
    type: ACTIONS.FETCHING
} | {
    type: ACTIONS.ERROR;
    error: string
} | {
    type: ACTIONS.FETCH_SUCCESS;
    data: DataType;
}

const initialState = {
  data: null,
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

interface State<DataType> {
  data: DataType | null;
  loading: boolean;
  error: string | null;
}

const reducer = <DataType extends any>(state: State<DataType>, action: ACTIONTYPES<DataType>) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.FETCHING: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    }
    case ACTIONS.FETCH_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        data: action.data,
      };
    }
    case ACTIONS.ERROR: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.error,
      };
    }
    default: {
        return state;
    }
  }
};

const useFetcher = <DataType extends any>(url: string): State<DataType> => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<Reducer<State<DataType>, ACTIONTYPES<DataType>>>(reducer, initialState);
  const { data, loading, error } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.FETCHING });
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await httpService.get(url);
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.FETCH_SUCCESS, data: response.data });
        return;
      } catch (error: unknown) {
        const { message } = error as Error;
        dispatch({ type: ACTIONS.ERROR, error: message });
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [url]);
  return { data, loading, error };
};

export default useFetcher;
```

Instead of using `Type extends State`, I am using the same generic value throughout, which refers to the type of `data` that we get from the server.  This is the only type that changes.

The part which is annoying is setting the generic on `useReducer` because the generic here needs to be the type of the *reducer* rather than the type of the *state*.  The react `Reducer` type is defined as `Reducer<S, A>` where `S` is the state type and `A` is the action type.  So we wind up with `Reducer<State<DataType>, ACTIONTYPES<DataType>>` which is the type of your `reducer` function, but limited to the specific `DataType`.

---

#### Using a Generic Hook

The `useFetcher` hook is fully generic and the API response data could be anything.  We are not limited to just `LIST_RESPONSE` and `CATEGORTY_RESPONSE`.

For example, you could do this:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useFetcher<string>('someUrl');
```

and the type of `data` will be inferred as `string | null`.

---

#### Defining a List Response

There's a problem with your current `LIST_RESPONSE` (and `CATEGORTY_RESPONSE`) type.  You have declared the type of the `list` property to be `[]` which is an empty array.  You need to say that it is an array whose elements are a specific type.

If the list item type is always the same then we can define a type for it and use `list: ListItem[];`.  If the type varies based on the URL then we can use another generic to describe it.

```
type LIST_RESPONSE<ItemType> = {
  page: number;
  totalRows: number;
  pageSize: number;
  totalPages: number;
  list: ItemType[];
};
```

We can then use your `useFetcher` hook for any type of list.  Like a list of products:

```
interface Product {
    price: number;
}
```

```
const { data, loading, error } = useFetcher<LIST_RESPONSE<Product>>('productList');

if ( data ) {

    // has type Product
    const product = data.list[0];

    // has type number
    const price = product.price;
}
```

If that's a bit confusing then you can think of it in steps.

A `ProductListResponse` is a specific type of `LIST_RESPONSE` where the list items are of the type `Product`:

```
type ProductListResponse = LIST_RESPONSE<Product>
```

Our `'productList'` endpoint returns `data` which has the type `ProductListResponse`:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useFetcher<ProductListResponse>('productList');
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/WolbLw)

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I'm looking for. Actually, the Reducer type was the obstacle that stops me from setting this up successfully when I was trying.  Now I learned a lot.

Comment: So helpful, @Linda, thank you! I was missing that `Reducer` type can be imported from "react"